# Dbeaver table locking

Tags: locking, production, mode, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver 5.0.5.
I  created a database connection and setted it to "production" type.
When I run an application which does a drop table on this database,
I got something like this :

*Query   | 1568 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE `meteo` |*

There aren't any other processes which use the table unless dbeaver.
Is that normal ?

Answer (score 10):

If you've marked your connection as Production, then it most likely disabled auto-commit mode. You need to commit the open transaction (click the commit button on the toolbar).

If you're like me and you don't do a whole lot of scripting that requires transactions, I find it easier to enable auto-commit in the connection settings and toggle it off on the toolbar when I need transactions.